# How to check that UIImageView has completed its animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I am new to iPhone development. I am using `UIImageView` to animate the images in an array. I am deciding that the animation is stopped through a property called `isAnimating`. But it always returns true.

I want to check that the animation is completed or there is some duration left to complete the animation.

Please let me know, how I can check it.

Comment: Can you show your animation code so we can help better?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

you should be doing your animation inside animation blocks:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    //animation code here
} completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    //this will be called when the animation is finished
}];
```

edit: this answer is wrong and probably shouldnt have been accepted, for anyone coming here looking for the right answer: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283270/access-method-after-uiimageview-animation-finish) answers this question i think

Comment: That I know, `animateWithDuration:completion:` is used to do iOS animations (such as alpha fade, motion, scaling, rotation, etc.)  I see that he accepted this answer, but I believe the original question had to do with detecting the end of a `UIImageView`'s animating an array of UIImages by setting the `animationImages` property.  I'd love to see an answer that talked about how to detect the end of that set of animations.

Answer (score 1):

Make a property BOOL IsAnimating 
then do this code

```
{
     [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animation of ImageVIew Begins" context:nil];
           IsAnimating =YES;

     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4]; //you can put your time
     NSLog(@" Animating");
     [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
     [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(AnimationComplete)];

// Your animation code here     
     [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void) AnimationComplete
{
  isAnimating = NO;
}
```

Your BOOl variable will be YES till the animation is complete..then it will change to NO

Comment: I'd up-vote this — if not sticking to the [naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002931-BBCFHEAB) wouldn't bug me so much

Answer (score 0):

Use a delegate based on the duration to trigger whatever method you want on the receiver.