# Access Method After UIImageView Animation Finish

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I have an array of images loaded into a UIImageView that I am animating through one cycle. After the images have been displayed, I would like a `@selector` to be called in order to dismiss the current view controller. The images are animated fine with this code:

```
NSArray * imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"HowTo1.png"], 
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"HowTo2.png"],
                        nil];
UIImageView * instructions = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

instructions.animationImages = imageArray;
[imageArray release];
instructions.animationDuration = 16.0;
instructions.animationRepeatCount = 1;
instructions.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
[instructions startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:instructions];
[instructions release];
```

After the 16 seconds, I would like a method to be called. I looked into the `UIView` class method `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` but I cannot get it to work with my current animation implementation. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animationDidFinish:) withObject:nil
    afterDelay:instructions.animationDuration];
```

or use `dispatch_after`:

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, instructions.animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self animationDidFinish];
});
```

Comment: This method seems to work fine, thanks rob! But i was wondering what would happen if for some reason the iPhone's frame-rate drop's a lot. Lets say from 30 to 15. In that case the animation wouldn't be finished playing when the dispatch timer run's out right?

Comment: Why do you think the frame rate dropping would make the animation take longer?  Maybe the image view drops frames if it can't keep up.

Comment: This is exactly the issue I am having with performSelector and delay. The array is too slow to load and loses time. Precision is lost. I need some other solution...

Comment: dispatch_after is inaccurate and can't be used in animation. Use CADisplayLink instead

Comment: `CADisplayLink` is good for syncing to individual display updates. This question is about detecting the end of an animation whose duration is not tied to the display's frame rate. However, if I were to try answering this question again today, I'd experiment with a wrapping the `UIImageView` animation in a `CATransaction` with a completion block.

Answer (score 24):

You can simple use this category [UIImageView-AnimationCompletionBlock](https://github.com/gurmundi7/UIImageView-AnimationCompletionBlock)

And for **Swift** version: [UIImageView-AnimationImagesCompletionBlock](https://github.com/wongzigii/UIImageView-AnimationImagesCompletionBlock)

Take a look on ReadMe file in this class..

Add **UIImageView+AnimationCompletion.h** and **UIImageView+AnimationCompletion.m** files in project and them import **UIImageView+AnimationCompletion.h** file where you want to use this..

For eg.

```
NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 10001 ; i<= 10010 ; i++)
    [imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i]]];

self.animatedImageView.animationImages = imagesArray;
self.animatedImageView.animationDuration = 2.0f;
self.animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 3;
[self.animatedImageView startAnimatingWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success){
 NSLog(@"Animation Completed",);}];
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to use this in swift. After adding to bridging header it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to do this precisely with UIImageView.  Using a delay will work most of the time, but there can be some lag after startAnimating is called before the animation happens on screen so its not precise.  Rather than using UIImageView for this animation try using a CAKeyframeAnimation which will call a delegate method when the animation is finished. Something along these lines:

```
NSArray * imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"HowTo1.png"].CGImage, 
                    (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"HowTo2.png"].CGImage,
                    nil];
UIImageView * instructions = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

//create animation
CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
[anim setKeyPath:@"contents"];
[anim setValues:imageArray];

[anim setRepeatCount:1];
[anim setDuration:1];
anim.delegate = self; // delegate animationDidStop method will be called

CALayer *myLayer = instructions.layer;

[myLayer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

Then just implement the animationDidStop delegate method

Comment: Can't add CGImage to array.

Comment: To get rid of the warning caused by adding CGImage to an array just cast it to id.

Comment: Answer edited to reflect above.  See [apples doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAKeyframeAnimation/values).

Answer (score 4):

With this method you avoid timers to fire while the imageView is still animating due to slow image loading.
You could use both `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` and GCD in this way:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(didFinishAnimatingImageView:)
           withObject:imageView
           afterDelay:imageView.animationDuration];
```

**/!\** `self.imageView.animationDuration` has to bet configured before `startAnimating`, otherwise it will be 0

Than if `-(void)didFinishAnimatingImageView:`create a background queue, perform a check on the `isAnimating` property, than execute the rest on the main queue

```
- (void)didFinishAnimatingImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView
{

   dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourcompany.yourapp.checkDidFinishAnimatingImageView", 0);
   dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

       while (self.imageView.isAnimating)
           NSLog(@"Is animating... Waiting...");

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          /* All the rest... */

       });

   });

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Created Swift Version from GurPreet_Singh Answer (UIImageView+AnimationCompletion)
I wasn't able to create a extension for UIImageView but I believe this is simple enough to use.

```
class AnimatedImageView: UIImageView, CAAnimationDelegate {

    var completion: ((_ completed: Bool) -> Void)?

    func startAnimate(completion: ((_ completed: Bool) -> Void)?) {
        self.completion = completion
        if let animationImages = animationImages {
            let cgImages = animationImages.map({ $0.cgImage as AnyObject })
            let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "contents")
            animation.values = cgImages
            animation.repeatCount = Float(self.animationRepeatCount)
            animation.duration = self.animationDuration
            animation.delegate = self

            self.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
        } else {
            self.completion?(false)
        }
    }

    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        completion?(flag)
    }
}


let imageView = AnimatedImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 135))
imageView.image = images.first
imageView.animationImages = images
imageView.animationDuration = 2
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
view.addSubview(imageView)

imageView.startAnimate { (completed) in
     print("animation is done \(completed)")
     imageView.image = images.last
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm only thing I added was `animation.calculationMode = .discrete` to disable the interpolation between the frames. It makes it look like a low fps gif.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a timer to fire after the duration of your animation. The callback could process your logic you want to execute after the animation finishes. In your callback be sure check the status of the animation `[UIImageView isAnimating]` just in case you want more time to let the animation finish.

Answer (score 1):

in ImageView.m

```
- (void) startAnimatingWithCompleted:(void (^)(void))completedHandler {
if (!self.isAnimating) {
    [self startAnimating];
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, self.animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(),completedHandler);       
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift**

```
func setupImageView() {
    
    if let GIF = UIImage().getGIF(imageName: "giphy") {
        
        let gifImageView = UIImageView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        gifImageView.animationImages = GIF.images
        gifImageView.animationDuration = GIF.duration
        gifImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
        gifImageView.startAnimating()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + GIF.duration, execute: {
            
            print("GIF Ended")
            gifImageView.stopAnimating()
        })
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    
    func getGIF(imageName: String) -> UIImage? {
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: imageName, withExtension: "gif")
        
        if let url = url {
            
            do {
                
                let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                
                return UIImage.animatedImage(withAnimatedGIFData: imageData)
                
            } catch {
                
                print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
                
                return nil
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```