# Delay between animation cycle on a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an `UIImageView` called imgView, where i have an array of images, like,

```
  imageArray objects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"test4.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"test5.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"test6.png"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"test7.png"],
                    nil];
```

then i have added the array images in imgView animation, like

```
imgView.animationImages = imageArray;
imgView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
imgView.animationDuration = 2.0f;

[imgView startAnimating];
```

Here every thing works fine. I have to delay 5sec after one cycle of animation finishes. How can i do this, i have used

```
 [self performSelector:@select...
```

but not working, please give me any idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    [self animationMethod];  //where you start the animation
}

-(void) animationMethod {
    NSMutableArray *imageArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnVideoEffectSample1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnVideoEffectSample2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnVideoEffectSample3.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnVideoEffectSample4.png"], nil];
    imgProfilePicture.animationImages = imageArray;
    imgProfilePicture.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    imgProfilePicture.animationDuration = 2.0f;
    [imgProfilePicture startAnimating];
    [imageArray release];

    double delayToStopAnimation = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t startTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayToStopAnimation * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(startTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [imgProfilePicture stopAnimating];

        double delayToRestartAnimation = 5.0;
        dispatch_time_t startTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayToRestartAnimation * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(startTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self animationMethod];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: what to do with animationMethod?

Comment: will u plz explain indetail?

Comment: i need to put all these lines? imgView.animationImages = imageArray;
imgView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
imgView.animationDuration = 2.0f;

[imgView startAnimating];

Answer (score 0):

After 1 cycle complete use `[imgView stopAnimating];`and remove from super view if want.After this put an `NSTimer` which will be called after 7 sec and again restart your animation because whole image cycle takes 2 sec and total time will be taken 2 sec to complete animation. After this you want 5 sec break then total time will be 7 sec.Again your method will start animation from  NStimer method calling like-

[`NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:7.0 target:self selector:@selector(startAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

If you have any problem please find this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283270/access-method-after-uiimageview-animation-finish)

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can i detect that one cycle has been completed?

Comment: when you start animating after 8 sec your cycle will be ended because each image has to take 2 sec and you have 4 images

Comment: after [imgView startAnimating]; given how can i detect 8 sec has been finished..?

Comment: Just stop animation after repeat count you can see it will take 8 sec

Comment: if you problem you can find link for image animation here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uiimageview-animation/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283270/access-method-after-uiimageview-animation-finish please use this link it is for you.