# How do I wait for one animation to finish before the next one starts in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uianimation

How do I wait for one animation to finish before the next one starts in Swift? I have been messing around with `if animation.animationDidStop... {}`, but it won't work.

Here's some of my code so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var purpleRing: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var beforeCountdownAnimation: UIImageView!

var imageArray = [UIImage]()
var imageArray2 = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for e in -17...0 {
    let imageName2 = "\(e)"
        imageArray2.append(UIImage(named: imageName2)!)
    }

    for t in 1...97 {
        let imageName = "\(t)"
        imageArray.append(UIImage(named: imageName)!)
    }
}

func startAnimation() -> Void {
    purpleRing.animationImages = imageArray
    purpleRing.animationDuration = 5.0
    purpleRing.startAnimating()
}

func startAnimation2() -> Void {
    beforeCountdownAnimation.animationImages = imageArray2
    beforeCountdownAnimation.animationDuration = 1.0
    beforeCountdownAnimation.startAnimating()
}

@IBAction func startAnimations(sender: AnyObject) {
    startAnimation()
    startAnimation2()
}
```

Comment: Using `class func animateWithDuration(_ duration: NSTimeInterval, animations animations: () -> Void, completion completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)` and calling the second animation on the completion?

Comment: and how exactly would I implement this in my code? :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread, you're using animationImages. I'd suggest you use the equivalent in Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283270/access-method-after-uiimageview-animation-finish

Answer (score 1):

Erm, probably answered before, but you can use Grand Central Dispatch dispatc_aysnc.

The idea is that, you know the animation duration, so you use that to tell the GDC when to execute the next code. So something like:

```
// call animation 1, which you specified to have 5 second duration
CGFloat animation1Duration = 5.0;
CGFloat animation2Duration = 7.0;

playAnimation1WithDuration(animation1Duration);

// calling second animation block of code after 5.0 using GDC
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(animation1Duration * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

    print("5.0 has passed");

    // call second animation block here
    playAnimation2WithDuration(animation2Duration);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For one animation after another you can use **NSTimer** as well...

See my code,it might help...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var IBimg1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var IBimg2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var IBimg3: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    startAnimation1()

}

func startAnimation1(){

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("startAnimation2"), userInfo: self, repeats: false)

UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {

        self.IBimg1.alpha = 0

    })

}

func startAnimation2(){

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("startAnimation3"), userInfo: self, repeats: false)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {

        self.IBimg2.alpha = 0

    })

}

func startAnimation3(){

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {

        self.IBimg3.alpha = 0

    })

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Explanation...

- Here **startAnimation1()** method is calling in **viewDidLoad()**
- Then i'm calling NSTimer's method  for **startAnimation2()**,
  Here note that **startAnimation2()** method is called after 2 seconds...,
  i.e After first animation finished...

Thanks